# (Illustrator) How to avoid including an item in an expanded Group or Layer when moving it in the Layers Panel?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, cc-2017

I just migrated from CS5 to CC and am being frustrated by an apparent removal of functionality of the *Layers* panel. I am habituated to the behavior in CS5 that allowed me to move an item to the bottom of an expanded group or layer and depending on where I dragged it to, the item could be included in the grouping or not. In Illustrator CC it seems that if the group or layer is expanded then dragging an item below it always includes it in the grouping.

Is there a way to reclaim the lost behavior or modify the new behavior to provide me with better control of where an item is placed?

This is especially frustrating when dealing with items in groups that I want to remove from the group but keep underneath the rest of the items in the group, because I cannot collapse the group while still accessing the item I want to remove from it.

Comment: I understand your issue, and it is indeed annoying. All I have found is that you must drag out of the group, collapse the group, then drag below the (collapsed) group. Any change to that is more of a technical support issue for Adobe to handle. Note that this behavior has been present since the CS6 release. So it's been around a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *slightly* easier way:

- Activate the object within the group by clicking on its 'meatball':

[image: Meatball clicking]

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to send the object to the top of the group
- Scroll to the top of the group and Drag the object up and out:

[image: A short way to go]

- Collapse the group
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to send the object below the group

Comment: thank you for the thorough answer and demonstrations. this or cut and paste-in-place have become the methods i rely on to work-around this issue.

Comment: @brnnnrsmssn You're welcome... Glad to help